# Passive voice for sentences like "He is going somewhere"

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity, intransitive-verbs

I have this sentence that I trying to render into passive voice:

> Tom is going to school.

According to the rules described in [this](http://www.e-grammar.org/download/passive_voice.pdf) document (“Passive voice with direct and indirect objects”), it should be like this:

> School is being gone by Tom.

I know that it is very artificial, but is this right?

Comment: You can't do it. If you applied the rules blindly, it would be: "School is being gone ***to*** by Tom", but it doesn't work because "to school" (as opposed to "to the school") is an expression that doesn't work in the passive.

Comment: No, it's not right simply because nobody ever says such things. It isn't even "artificial": it's **absurd**. I vote to close as not constructive.

Comment: Passives are created from transitive verbs, not intransitive ones.

Comment: @tchrist: Is that always true? Can't you say "he fell off the supply wagon and  was trodden on by a mule"? See [this discussion](http://books.google.com/books?id=zZ42f_YuT0UC&pg=PA138&dq=%22was+stepped+on+by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y0ptUdeDHOfk4AOGuoHoBQ&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22was%20stepped%20on%20by%22&f=false), which calls it the "pseudo-passive" or "prepositional passive", and notes there are restrictive constraints about when it can be used. (As opposed to transitive verbs, which can usually be put into the passive.)

Comment: @PeterShor Do you not find *to step on someone* to be a transitive construction?  The mule is doing the acting and someone is receiving that action.  In contrast, when you have “the river runs down from the mountain”, there is no chance for subject–object inversion because there is no object the way there is with “the car ran over the man”.

Comment: @tchrist oh but it sounds so nice to say "Down from the mountain, the river runs". Makes me feel green and three feet tall ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that you end up with a very unidiomatic sentence shows the value of this sort of exercise (there isn't much).

The *to* is a preposition which you need to retain.

> Tom is going to school.
>   *School is being gone to by Tom.

However *going to* cannot be passivised like this. *Go* is intransitive and it just doesn't work — that's probably why it's not mentioned in your reference.

You **can** turn a transitive verb like *visit* into a passive construction:

> Tom is visiting the school.
>   The school is being visited by Tom.

Again, although it is grammatical, such a passive sentence would be used only rarely.